# TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined discord.js bot

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I'm having trouble implementing a feature on my discord bot, everything else is fine except this part of the code gives and error 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined'

```js
function jailCheck(guild, member) {
  if (!member.roles.find(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === "prisonnier")) return;

  if (typeof member.voiceChannel !== "undefined" && member.voiceChannel.name !== getJailChannel(guild).name) {
    member.setVoiceChannel(getJailChannel(guild))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed to move member: " + err);
      });
  }
}
```

I've tried using other ways to find the member's role from similar issues I found on the site but still no luck. How do I fix this?

Here is the complete code:

```js
function getJailChannel(guild) {
  return guild.channels.find(channel => channel.type === "voice" && channel.name.toLowerCase() === "Jaill");
}

function jailCheck(guild, member) {
  if (!member.roles.find(e => e.name.toLowerCase() === "prisonnier")) return;

  if (typeof member.voiceChannel !== "undefined" && member.voiceChannel.name !== getJailChannel(guild).name) {
    member.setVoiceChannel(getJailChannel(guild))
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed to move member: " + err);
      });
  }
}

client.on("message", async function(message) {
  if (message.channel.type !== "text") return;
  if (message.author.bot) return;

  if (message.content.startsWith(prefix + "jail")) {
    var member = message.mentions.members.first();
    if (typeof member === "undefined") {
      message.channel.send('You must mention a valid user!');
      return;
    }


    var jailedRole = message.guild.roles.find(role => role.name.toLowerCase() === "jailedd");
    if (jailedRole === null) {
      message.channel.send('This guild does not have a \"Prisonnier\" role!');
      return;
    }

    if (!member.manageable) {
      message.channel.send('I do not have the permissions necessaryy to punish this member!');
      return;
    }

    member.roles.forEach(role => {
      member.removeRole(role.id)
        .catch(err => {
          console.log("Failed to remove role: " + err);
        });
    });

    member.addRole(jailedRole.id)
      .catch(err => {
        console.log("Failed to add role: " + err);
      });

    message.channel.send("Jailed " + member.displayName + "!");

    jailCheck(message.guild, member);

  };

});
```

Comment: what version of discord.js

Comment: Are you sure that "member" is not null?

Comment: Well that depends when you call `jailCheck()` which variable do you give member?

Comment: @BeamKunGzMARK I'm using discord.js 11.5.1

Comment: @Jakye I don't think so, becuase I'm using 'member' outside the function to check if the member is manageable and it works just fine.

Comment: Please check line 59.
You are calling the jailCheck() function with only one parameter, resulting in member being null.

Comment: @Jakye Thank you. It fixed the issue!